# Dúvida sobre alterar variável em outro controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma tela composta por um menu lateral(controller1) e um menu no topo(controller1).

Ao clicar no link do menu do topo, a aplicação carrega informações no menu lateral, assim como a página em uma div central(controller2).

Um novo requisito foi introduzido: ao clicar em uma opção do menu lateral, uma div deve ser aberta dentro da div central que por padrão é fechada durante a inicialização. Assim, preciso abri-la; porém estou em controllers diferentes.

Qual a melhor prática para efetuar tal operação?

Answer (score 1):

pesquisa sobre `UI-Router Angular`.
Exemplo:

```
.state('customers.edit', {
    url: '/edit/:customerId',
    views:{ '' :{ templateUrl: 'views/customers/edit.html'},
            'form@customers.edit':{templateUrl:'views/customers/form.html',
    controller: 'EditCustomerController as genericCustomersViewModel'}},
    controller: 'EditCustomerController as genericCustomersViewModel'}
```

Ali no form é o nome do meu ui-view.

Comment: Não posso fazer dessa maneira, porque minhas rotas são feitas pelo vnx do asp.net 5, então eu não uso o router do angular.

Comment: Neste ponto eu não sei lhe ajuda =/

Answer (score 0):

Consegui utilizando $broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar o conceito de eventos no angular, através do $emit e $on. É necessário o uso do $rootScope.

O $emit é quem envia os dados e o $on é quem recebe.

Na controller que você quer enviar dados, use o $emit, você tem dois parametros na função, primeiro é o nome do evento e o segundo é valor que quer enviar.

```
$rootScope.$emit('enviarDados', 'hello world');
```

Na controller que você quer receber dados, use o $on, você tem dois parametros na função, primeiro é o nome do evento e o segundo é o valor de retorno através de um callback.

```
$rootScope.$on('enviarDados', function(event, valor){
     $scope.nome = valor;
});
```

Veja um exemplo nesse [link](http://jsbin.com/necida/edit?html,js,console,output)